# Detect background of image and change it to black using Aforge

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, aforge

I'm using Aforge's library to working with Image processing. BlobsCounter class work very to find out some standalone object, but it needs the background of the image is black. So my question is do we have any ways to detect the background of the image and change it to black that help BlobsCounter can work well.

**Real image**

[image]

**Expectation image**

[image]

Comment: If you can detect the background you have the blobs (blob == non background connected component) so it is kind of a dual problem

Comment: @RosaGronchi I am using Aforge framework that helps me to blobs in the image but just work on black background, so that why I want to detect and change it into black.